# Add Java file to Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml

I am very new to Android development. I have created multiple xml layout files in my res folder for different screens in my application, but is there a way to connect those files with Java files in the src folder? I want a java file for each xml layout file. Similar to how there is a automatically a Java file associated with a xml layout file in a new Android project.

Comment: i prefer you to study the deference between the java file and a activity in the android and please tell what effort you did for connect this all

Comment: Refer these tutorials http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/android-tutorial/

Comment: google is your best friend....

Comment: This question is too broad. Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding that can have definite answers, not for general pointers, advice, and discussion. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Few leads you can follow if you want to understand Android and its development. visit Slidener videos on youtube.com for Android development. Go thru links suggested by links above by other contributor. I have answered your question but advice you to add your research to avoid down votes from senior contributor. Anyways all were new bie once... :D

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial links, I'll try to ask questions more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any .java file that extends Activity class has associated Layout.xml file most probably. And any of this class who has layout.xml should be defined in Androidmanifest.xml file's Activity tag under intent Filter.

Now coming to your question when you have created your Android Application using eclipse, you have selected a blank activity so automatically eclipse generated Android layout file and corresponding Main Activity java class then in Android manifest it says Main launcher path like below:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.yourpackage.urclassname"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Now, you want java file sync up for your developed Layout files, Its Quite simple to do.

1. Just create a . java file in you package and extend its with Activity.
2. Now you will have to override default super class function i.e onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) and simply add setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator); where activity_calculator is xml file in my case and you are done...

I hope this answer your question ?

Comment: Good to know this... :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept called each java file for xml layout file. Please go through the UI guideline before creating an[android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things first its not necessary each java file for xml layout file second if your totally new to Android See this [Android Article by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html)  and [Developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) and also [Get Started Developing for Android](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/25/get-started-developing-for-android-with-eclipse/)
In this see **LINKING YOUR LAYOUT WITH CODE** may be help full to you. Now as you ask  **there is a automatically a Java file associated with a xml layout**  Yes but its called Activity Class which created when you start new project and linked by your layout using `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`.